# Selecting string followed by space in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select strings which are followed by space.I am very new to regex.I know it is a silly question.

```
var string = "I am a good boy";
```

I want to select am,a,good,boy. and i am not able to use look-behind.

Comment: "boy" is not followed by a space, but you still want to select it. "I" however is, but you left it out. Please either correct your question or your example.

Comment: i want to select a string which starts with a space.

Comment: Then please state your question this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
\s([^\s]+)
```

And extract `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cJ5pY2/7)

Comment: but it is also selecting " I ".